# How can I do such that when a person enters a letter and hits enter, it will see if the letter corresponds to the question?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Excuse the bad wording of the title, I couldn't exactly figure out how to explain it in few words. Currently I have a code for the Stroop Test, and the different words show up with the different colors and all of that. I have it such that you type the first letter of the color (so if the color is green you type "g" and hit enter), but the problem is I don't know how to make it say if you got it correct or not. The color will be green and I will type g, but it does not give that as a correct answer.

I've asked on here about this code before, and now I've worked on it for a bit. I don't know too much about coding but I've tried to make an answer variable and then match that answer variable with the current color in an if statement, to make it say "Correct" or "Incorrect", but this does not seem to work.

```
from turtle import Turtle, turtle, Screen
import random
screen = Screen()
screen.setup(500, 100)
tina = turtle.Turtle()
tina.hideturtle()
tina.speed(0)
colors = ['blue','yellow','green','red']
texts = ['Blue','Yellow','Green','Red']
nooftrials = 0
correct = 0
begin = str(raw_input("Begin the test? "))
if begin == 'y' or 'yes' or 'Yes':
  while nooftrials <= 10:
    color = random.choice(colors)
    text = random.choice(texts)
    tina.color(color);style1 = ('Arial', 20, 'bold');style2 = ('Arial', 20, 'bold');tina.write(text, font=style1, align='center')
    answer = str(raw_input("Letter of color: "))
    nooftrials += 1
    if answer == color:
      tina.clear()
      tina.color('black');tina.write('Correct!', font=style2, align='center')
      correct += 1
      cont = str(raw_input('Press enter to continue'))
      if cont == '':
        tina.clear()
      else:
        tina.clear()
        break
    else:
      tina.clear()
      tina.color('black');tina.write('Incorrect', font=style2, align='center')
      cont = str(raw_input('Press enter to continue'))
      if cont == '':
        tina.clear()
      else:
        tina.clear()
        break
  tina.clear()
  tina.write('Test is over. You scored %s' %correct + ' out of 10', font=style2, align='center')
```

The expected result is that when you enter the letter of the color, if you get it correct, it will say "Correct!" and add a point to the amount of answers correct, and if you get it wrong, it will say "Incorrect" and won't add any points. Right now, it just says "Incorrect" for everything, regardless of whether it's correct or not.

Comment: Have you tried printing `answer` and `color` just before the if statement to check that they're actually what you expect them to be?

Comment: Not an answer, but if you have multiple statements, always put them on new lines, instead of separating them by `;`. This is bad, hard-to-read style, especially in Python where you usually don't terminate statements by `;`

Comment: Also `if begin == 'y' or 'yes' or 'Yes':` does not do what you expect it to. You might notice, that no matter what you enter after the question `Begin the test?`, it will always begin. If you want to test multiple possibilities, you need to repeat the comparison: `begin == 'y' or begin == 'yes' or begin == 'Yes'` (or use `in` with a list).

Comment: For the actual question: Consider that you are asking the user for a letter of the color, but you choose them from `colors` which has full color names. Now depending on what the user actually enters, do you see a problem comparing these two things in `if answer == color:`?

Answer (score 0):

I altered your code a bit, and it seems that this code will solve your issue.

First, I added an answer list:

```
answer_list = ['b', 'y', 'g', 'r']
colors      = ['blue','yellow','green','red']
texts       = ['Blue','Yellow','Green','Red']
```

Then, I draw a random number between 0 and 3 (both included), to determine what color the word will be:

```
index = random.randint(0, len(colors) - 1)
color = colors[index]
```

Note I use the function `random.randint()` for this.
Type `help(random.randint())` if this function is unfamiliar.

Finally, I compared the response that was given (i.e. the letter) with the variables in `answer_list` using the index I randomly decided:

```
if answer == answer_list[index]:
      tina.clear()
      tina.color('black')
...
```

**Example**

**random index = 2**

- Then the word will be colored *green*
- The participant will type 'g'
- g is compared with `answer_list[2]`
- `g == answer_list[2]`, so the answer is correct!

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I haven't had a chance to try it out yet but it makes sense and seems like it would work. Thanks also for clearly explaining every step you did, it really helps. Keep up the good work!